# Woocommerce filter query backend

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I filter the product to specific things?

I got the next code:

```
            $post_query .= array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'post_type' => 'tc_events',
                'post_author' => $user_ID
            ),
            array(
                'post_type' => 'tc_templates',
                'post_author' => $user_ID
            ),
            array(
                'post_type' => 'tc_templates',
                'post_title' => 'Default'
            ),              
        );

        $query->set( $post_query );
```

I would like to filter out some post_types to specific author and a post_type to a post title.

I guess I got something wrong, I don't know how edit the post query...

Comment: Tried to use tax_query.. also no result:

   $post_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'post_type' => array('tc_events', 'tc_templates'),
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'title',
      'terms'    => array( 'Default' ),
      'operator' => 'IN',
     ),
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'author',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => array( $user_ID, 0 ),
     )
    ),    
   ); 
   
   $query->set( 'tax_query', $post_query );